# How to get the "Call me Mr. Pig" achievement?

Tags: achievements, kingdom-rush-origins

The description reads "Make the Razor Boars trample and kill 20 enemies." By replaying both the campaign and iron mode over 10 times, using not upgraded barracks behind mage and archer towers ahead of them to trigger the boars' charge, I've certainly seen more than 20 soldiers being killed by a charging boar. Questions:

1. Should the description read "...in one game"?
2. Or is this achievement bugged, or I misunderstand otherwise?
3. Any good suggestions how to do this? The only hints I found casually given [here](http://www.ironhidegames.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=6320) were not helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1° It should not be in one game

2° That troubles me :

> I've certainly seen more than 20 soldiers being killed by a charging boar

You mean *your* soldiers ? The boars must kill your *ennemies*.

I found some advice in the link you gave pretty useful :

- map 12, "The Ascent", seems to be a good choice, since it has boars and lots of spiders
- using teleport (max mage tower + scrolls) to put the boars behind packs of spiders, and luring them to charge with summoning reinforcements is efficient

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can the boar kill my enemy? When it tramples/charges, it kills other enemies? I'm doing what the advice says (map, layout, ...), but it's true, I've never seen 20 *in one game*.

Comment: When the boars charge, they damage everything in their way, friend or foe. Which explains the luring by summoning reinforcements.

Comment: Yeah that worked - hard to get an achievement if you try to do something different. :) However, it doesn't have to be in one game. Turns out I was just one such charge-kill short of the achievement.